# How to record audio with AVAudioEngine with seek position to overwrite the sound?

Tags: swift, record, avaudioengine

Apple's Memos Recorder app can overwrite previously recorded audio. During your recording, you can `PAUSE` and move back on audio and record on it again. I want to clone this feature.

I create an `AVAudioEngine` and install a `TAP` on the output of `mainMixer` and write the `PCMBuffer` down to a file. I can save file in different linear PCM Formats. The problem is when I want to set `AudioFile.framePosition` it calls the `EXTAudioFileSeek()` function. This function as Apple's documentation mentioned: "This function’s behavior with files open for writing is undefined.". I then get follwoing error:

`EXCEPTION (-66568): "seek to frame in audio file"`

It means I can not use this function to seek the position on AudioFile that created for writing. (I accept it)

I want to know do we have another function in Core Audio that help me to write from a position on a AudioFile?

I follow [@RomanTsopin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388730/recording-audio-file-using-avaudioengine) structure and it works properly.

```swift
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
var file: AVAudioFile?
var player = AVAudioPlayerNode() // if you need play record later

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    file = AVAudioFile(forWriting: URLFor("my_file.caf")!, settings: engine.inputNode.inputFormatForBus(0).settings, error: nil)
    engine.attachNode(player)
    engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0)) //configure graph
    engine.startAndReturnError(nil)
}

@IBAction func record(sender: AnyObject) {
    engine.inputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: 1024, format: engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0)) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        self.file?.writeFromBuffer(buffer, error: nil)
        return
    }
}

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    engine.inputNode.removeTapOnBus(0)
}


func URLFor(filename: String) -> NSURL? {
    if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
        let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    }
    return nil
}
```

After pause the recording, I want to change the position of writing pointer and write from that position into file.

I am going to try `AudioFileWritePackets` because it gets `inStartingPacket` (The packet index for the placement of the first provided packet.)

What do you think? Any idea can help, thanks.

Comment: You’ll need to use [Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_file_services) to seek and write rather than append. It’s the most powerful of the audio file APIs, but not the most fun.

Comment: Thanks @dave234 I have another question can I use AVAudioEngine and Audio File Services at the same time?